# How to upload a file to the file.io website using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to send a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request to the *file.io* website to upload a file from my Python script and I want to get the link for that file. Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://file.io/post'
files = {"file": open("myimage.jpg", "rb")}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
link = response.json()['link']

print(link)
```

When I print the response code, I get 200. Everything seems OK, but I can’t get the link of the uploaded file. I get an error.
I want to be able to upload a file I specify and get back a link using my little Python script.

Comment: I think it's not returning the URL. Actually, it is returning the HTML. You can check using the following line.
data = response.content

Comment: it returns b'html code of the page'

Comment: So that's what websites return it is not returning the URL.

Comment: can you please correct the code? i would really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I tried. I think your URL should not contains `/post`

```py
import requests

url = 'https://file.io/'
data = {
    "file": open("myimage.png", "rb"),
    "maxDownloads": 100,
    "autoDelete": True
}
response = requests.post(url, files=data)
res = response.json()
print(res)
print(res["link"])
```

and results in

```json
{'success': True, 'status': 200, 'id': '800e35c0-01eb-11ec-95c3-335b9c818244', 'key': 'zZRteNaopzbt', 'name': 'myimage.png', 'link': 'https://file.io/zZRteNaopzbt', 'private': False, 'expires': '2021-09-03T19:19:11.898Z', 'downloads': 0, 'maxDownloads': 1, 'autoDelete': True, 'size': 1552900, 'mimeType': 'text/plain', 'created': '2021-08-20T19:19:11.898Z', 'modified': '2021-08-20T19:19:11.898Z'}
```

```
https://file.io/zZRteNaopzbt
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change maxDownloads and autoDelete values when sending post?

Comment: @Sahar I have updated the code have a look, but the `maxDownload` requires API_KEY

Comment: Wow. Awesome! In case i get the api key where should i put it in this request?

Comment: that much you can explore yourself

Comment: This code no longer works. Copy/pasted and file.io returns error 'Multiple file uploads are not supported' data{} should only contain the file, then it works.

Comment: I got `KeyError: 'link'`

Answer (score 0):

Tried in 2022:

```py
import requests
from pathlib import Path

res = requests.post(
    url=r'https://file.io',
    files={
        'file': Path('string_path').read_bytes()
    }
)
print(res.json())
```

```py
{
    'success': True,
    'status': 200,
    'id': '39bc5ef0-b533-11ee-8841-8500e8190f61',
    'key': 'B0Y3F20Tyzab',
    'path': '/',
    'nodeType': 'file',
    'name': 'file',
    'title': None,
    'description': None,
    'size': 6,
    'link': 'https://file.io/B0Y3F20Tyzab',
    'private': False,
    'expires': '2024-01-31T12:23:31.158Z',
    'downloads': 0,
    'maxDownloads': 1,
    'autoDelete': True,
    'planId': 0,
    'screeningStatus': 'pending',
    'mimeType': 'text/plain',
    'created': '2024-01-17T12:23:31.158Z',
    'modified': '2024-01-17T12:23:31.158Z'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the one who concerned: I had written a wrapper for file.io:**

#### Install

```bash
pip install fileio-wrapper
```

#### Upload without authenticate

```py
from fileio_wrapper import Fileio

resp = Fileio.upload(filepath)
success = resp['success']  # True if upload was successful
status = resp['status']  # HTTP status code
key = resp['key']  # ID of uploaded file
link = resp['link']  # Link to file (not a direct link)
```

#### Upload with authenticate

```py
from fileio_wrapper import Fileio

fileio = Fileio(fileio_api_key)
resp = fileio.upload(filepath)
success = resp['success']  # True if upload was successful
status = resp['status']  # HTTP status code
key = resp['key']  # ID of uploaded file
link = resp['link']  # Link to file (not a direct link)
```

#### More detail (Config, Update, Delete, Download, etc...)

Give me a star for the project and I'll be happy.
https://github.com/chumicat/fileio_wrapper